# Rooting issue on my xperia m

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia

I have got my Xperia M and somehow now it says "Type password to decrypt storage." I have tried all ways but nothing has helped. Will rooting the phone help my cause? Will it remove the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information about this out there, so I suggest you try searching first and then come back if you are still stuck. [This search](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=xperia+m+type+password+to+decrypt+storage) should get you started.

Unfortunately, I think you're going to have to factory reset the device, which means you will lose your data and installed apps. I really don't think rooting is going to help you since that will not give you the needed decryption key in itself.

Hopefully you have a backup. Good luck.

Comment: I have already tried factory reset opton,but its of no use.. What more can i do?

Comment: Any one found solution?